# Applescript to get file name without extension

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript where the user will pick one file and i need to get the name of that file minus the extension.

I found a post on a different site that said this would work:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set short_name to name of selected_file
end tell
```

But it returns the extensions as well. How can I get just the name of the file?

Answer (score 4):

You can ask the **Finder** or **System Events** for the *name extension* and remove that part from the full name.  This will also avoid issues with names that have periods in them or extensions that may not be what *you* think they are.

```
set someItem to (choose file)

tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (someItem as text) to set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension}
if theExtension is not "" then set theName to text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 2) of theName -- the name part

log theName & tab & theExtension
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approach, there are many problems inherent with telling finder to do something

Answer (score 2):

This should work with filenames that contain periods and ones that don't have an extension (but not both). It returns the last extension for files that have multiple extensions.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set n to name of file "test.txt" of desktop
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    if number of text items of n > 1 then
        set n to text items 1 thru -2 of n as text
    end if
    n
end tell
```

`name extension` also returns the last extension for files with more than one extension:

```
tell application "Finder"
    name extension of file "archive.tar.gz" of desktop -- gz
end tell
```

Comment: Don't forget to set your text item delim to original value...set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
(* do your processing here *)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script for getting just the filenames.

```
set filesFound to {}
set filesFound2 to {}
set nextItem to 1

tell application "Finder"
  set myFiles to name of every file of (path to desktop) --change path to whatever path you want   
end tell

--loop used for populating list filesFound with all filenames found (name + extension)
repeat with i in myFiles
  set end of filesFound to (item nextItem of myFiles)
  set nextItem to (nextItem + 1)
end repeat

set nextItem to 1 --reset counter to 1

--loop used for pulling each filename from list filesFound and then strip the extension   
--from filename and populate a new list called filesFound2
repeat with i in filesFound
  set myFile2 to item nextItem of filesFound
  set myFile3 to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in myFile2) - 1) of myFile2
  set end of filesFound2 to myFile3
  set nextItem to (nextItem + 1)
end repeat

return filesFound2
```

Comment: If the filename itself contains periods, the script currently returns the part before the first period.

Answer (score 0):

This script uses ASObjC Runner to parse file paths. Download  [ASObjC Runner here.](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner_vanilla.html)

```
set aFile to choose file
tell application "ASObjC Runner" to set nameS to name stub of (parsed path of (aFile as text))
```